# How to identify which community Users is coming at run time apex

Tags: apex, community, community-builder

We have five communities in our org. We have bunch of common components in ORGS which common among org. Can we identify at run time in apex call is coming from which community.

Let suppose we have comm1, comm2, coom3, comm4 & comm5.

We are trying to implement logic like,

```
 if( comm1){


}
if( comm2){


}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I would expected the Apex call [Network.getNetworkId()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_network.htm) to return an Id that you can then used to query the [Network](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_network.htm) object to e.g. return the community name.

(But watch out in unit tests - this method will return null there. So you will have to use e.g. `Test.isRunningTest` to add test-only fake code.)

Comment: Thank you. Let me try that.